# How can I determine the size of each worksheet in a .xlsb file?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, vba, office365, zip

Working on Windwos 10 Enterprise with Excel from Office 365 version 2204, I have a large `.xlsb` file (>14MB) and want to determine the size of the single worksheets in kB/MB, optimally saving this information in tabulated form.

I have tried (various versions of these) two approaches without success

1. **zip-File**, e.g., described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/739577/how-can-i-find-out-which-parts-of-an-excel-workbook-are-the-biggest-in-size)
   Renaming the file-type to `.zip` and
   looking into `FILENAME/xl/workbook.xml` and the
   `FILENAME/xl/worksheets` folder does not work: Whenever I would expect a `.xml`-file, I find a `.bin`-file, which I cannot read and furthermore, the sum of single sheet sizes is way too high.
2. **Macros**, e.g., [here](https://www.excelhow.net/how-to-get-the-data-size-of-each-worksheet-in-a-workbook.html)
   There are several differnt versions of macros out there, which all break in my case at a line where they measure the size of current file with the function `FileLen(...)`. I couldn't find out if this error happens due to working in an `.xlsb` or whether a limit of the function is reached.

How can I determine the size of each worksheet?

Any thoughts appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Open the file? What do you mean, exactly, by the size of a worksheet?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad The entire .xlsb file is a "workbook", containing several "worksheets" - see screenshot/explanation here: https://excelnotes.com/what-is-the-difference-between-workbook-and-worksheet/

Comment: Thanks, in spite of using Excel for decades now, I had absolutely no idea...

Comment: That's not really hope XLSB files work, there's some overhead, even with an empty workbook the file has a particular size, but zipping (compressing) in general works better with similar content, so a workbook with two worksheets that are similar will compress more. The worksheets in separate workbooks would add up to far greater size than the size of a combined workbook. You could estimate based on number of filled cells per worksheet if you want to know what each sheet contributes to the overall size? Any reason for this?

Comment: @pbhj Thanks for the background and the next ideas!
The reason I am doing this is as follows:
The .xlsb file is a excel tool (containing many formulas, (conditional) formatting, references, etc.) which should be used by many people, thus I want to understand how I can scale down on size to make it more usable - to scale down size, I need to know where the size is hidden. [Just for the record: a python based web-app or similar is unfortunately no option].

Since formatting and formulas are a large part of it, only looking at number of cells won't likely be sufficient.

Comment: Filesize does not matter much (eg [performance of Excel study ](https://trumpexcel.com/reduce-excel-file-size/)). For sending via email maybe do pivot cache removal ([with other size saving tips](https://trumpexcel.com/reduce-excel-file-size/#Remove-Pivot-Cache-to-Save-Space) or [from MS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/reduce-the-file-size-of-your-excel-spreadsheets-c4f69e3a-8eea-4e9d-8ded-0ac301192bf9)). To improve speed see 1st link or [MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/excel-performance/excel-tips-for-optimizing-performance-obstructions).

Answer (score 0):

The article
[How to check the size of each worksheet of workbook](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1682-excel-check-size-of-each-sheet.html)
proposes using a VBA macro for this calculation.

- Hold <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor
- Click menu *Insert > Module*
- Paste the following code in the Module Window :

  ```
    Sub WorksheetSizes()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim xOutWs As Worksheet
    Dim xOutFile As String
    Dim xOutName As String
    xOutName = "KutoolsforExcel"
    xOutFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TempWb.xls"
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Err = 0
    Set xOutWs = Application.Worksheets(xOutName)
    If Err = 0 Then
        xOutWs.Delete
        Err = 0
    End If
    With Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Before:=Application.Worksheets(1))
        .Name = xOutName
        .Range("A1").Resize(1, 2).Value = Array("Worksheet Name", "Size")
    End With
    Set xOutWs = Application.Worksheets(xOutName)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xIndex = 1
    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If xWs.Name <> xOutName Then
            xWs.Copy
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xOutFile
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Set Rng = xOutWs.Range("A1").Offset(xIndex, 0)
            Rng.Resize(1, 2).Value = Array(xWs.Name, VBA.FileLen(xOutFile))
            Kill xOutFile
            xIndex = xIndex + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub
  ```
- Press F5 key to execute this code
- A new worksheet named "KutoolsforExcel" will be inserted into the
  current workbook which contains each worksheet name and file size
  in bytes:

  [image]

Comment: thanks for pointing me to this. Interestingly, this macro breaks without any error message / room to debug. When running the full macro it breaks after some 15 worksheets (Excel just closes the workbook), If I am running the macro just for a single sheet, it breaks immediately.
Changing the name of the temporary workbook to TempWB.xlsb increased performance slightly, but didn't change the break without error message.

I am really puzzled.